# How to make clock ticks stuck to the clock border?

Tags: xcode, swift, osx-yosemite

I try to make a clock, in swift, but now i want to make something strange. I want make border radius settable. This is the easy part (is easy because I already did that). I drew 60 ticks around the clock. The problem is that 60 ticks are a perfect circle. If I change the border radius I obtain this  clock:

[image]

All ticks are made with NSBezierPath, and  code for calculate position for every tick is :

```
tickPath.moveToPoint(CGPoint(
            x: center.x + cos(angle) *  point1 ,
            y: center.y + sin(angle) * point1
            ))

        tickPath.lineToPoint(CGPoint(
            x: center.x + cos(angle) * point2,
            y: center.y + sin(angle) * point2
            ))
```

point1 and point2 are points for 12 clock tick.

My clock background is made with bezier path:

```
 let bezierPath = NSBezierPath(roundedRect:self.bounds, xRadius:currentRadius, yRadius:currentRadius)
```

currentRadius - is a settable var , so my background cam be, from a perfect circle (when corner radius = height / 2) to a square (when corner radius = 0 ).

Is any formula to calculate position for every tick so, for any border radius  , in the end all ticks to be at same distance to border ?

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to ask. It looks to me like you've got your ticks so that the outside of each tick lies on your outer radius. What are you trying to do differently?

Comment: I did update my question.

Comment: This is a really interesting question, but not really from a Swift or Xcode perspective - it's more of a maths question. I've spent about an hour on it today, and I'm some-way there, but it will take me a while more time. I suggest that you re-ask it on Stack Exchange's maths site - http://math.stackexchange.com (it's clear that you know how to draw it if only you knew the coordinates!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The maths is rather complicated to explain without recourse to graphics diagrams, but basically if you consider a polar coordinates approach with the origin at the clock centre then there are two cases:

- where the spoke from the origin hits the straight side of the square - easy by trigonometry
- where it hits the circle arc at the corner - we use the cosine rule to solve the triangle formed by the centre of the clock, the centre of the corner circle and the point where the spoke crosses the corner. The origin-wards angle of that triangle is 45º - angleOfSpoke, and two of the sides are of known length. Solve the cosine equation as a quadratic and you have it.

This function does it:

```
func radiusAtAngle(angleOfSpoke: Double, radius: Double, cornerRadius: Double) -> Double {
    // radius is the half-width of the square, = the full radius of the circle
    // cornerRadius is, of course, the corner radius. 
    // angleOfSpoke is the (maths convention) angle of the spoke
    // the function returns the radius of the spoke.

    let theta = atan((radius - cornerRadius) / radius) // This determines which case

    let modAngle = angleOfSpoke % M_PI_2 // By symmetry we need only consider the first quadrant

    if modAngle <= theta { // it's on the vertical flat
        return radius / cos(modAngle)
    } else if modAngle > M_PI_2 - theta { // it's on the horizontal flat
        return radius / cos(M_PI_2 - modAngle)
    } else { // it's on the corner arc
        // We are using the cosine rule to solve the triangle formed by
        // the clock centre, the curved corner's centre,
        // and the point of intersection of the spoke.
        // Then use quadratic solution to solve for the radius.
        let diagonal = hypot(radius - cornerRadius, radius - cornerRadius)
        let rcosa = diagonal * cos(M_PI_4 - modAngle)
        let sqrTerm = rcosa * rcosa - diagonal * diagonal + cornerRadius * cornerRadius
        if sqrTerm < 0.0 {
            println("Aaargh - Negative term") // Doesn't happen - use assert in production
            return 0.0
        } else {
            return rcosa + sqrt(sqrTerm) // larger of the two solutions
        }
    }
}
```

In the diagram OP = diagonal, OA = radius, PS = PB = cornerRadius, OS = function return, BÔX = theta, SÔX = angleOfSpoke

[image: Diagram of solution]

Comment: This is the best answer a could recive. Thank you.